# Regexp get last part of url without parameters if they exists

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I looking for regular expression to use in my javascript code, which give me last part of url without parameters **if they exists** - here is example - with and without parameters:

https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14238253_132683573850463_7287992614234853254_n.jpg?oh=fdbf6800f33876a86ed17835cfce8e3b&oe=599548AC

https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14238253_132683573850463_7287992614234853254_n.jpg

In both cases as result I want to get:

**14238253_132683573850463_7287992614234853254_n.jpg**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is this regexp

`.*\/([^?]+)`

and JS code:

```
let lastUrlPart = /.*\/([^?]+)/.exec(url)[1];
```

```js
let lastUrlPart = url => /.*\/([^?]+)/.exec(url)[1];



// TEST

let t1 = "https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14238253_132683573850463_7287992614234853254_n.jpg?oh=fdbf6800f33876a86ed17835cfce8e3b&oe=599548AC"

let t2 = "https://scontent-fra3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/14238253_132683573850463_7287992614234853254_n.jpg"

console.log(lastUrlPart(t1));
console.log(lastUrlPart(t2));
```

May be there are better alternatives?

Comment: I don't know if it's better but you could try it at least. `(?!\/)\w+(?=.jpg)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try doing it without regex. Split the URL by "/" and then parse out the last part of the URL.

```
var urlPart = url.split("/");
var img = urlPart[urlPart.length-1].split("?")[0];
```

That should get everything after the last "/" and before the first "?".